# Checking with PHP should table update should be done

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi to all of you programmers. I want disable table update in my database if inputted value is lower than value in db. The code looks ok, but update always executes. This is my code:

```
$sql="UPDATE student SET _id_year='$_year' WHERE _index='$_index'";
$check1="SELECT _id_year FROM student WHERE _index='$_index'";

if('$_year'>'$check1')
{
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
```

Note: _id_year and _index are values from DB, and `$_year`,`$_index` are inputted values.
`$con` is connection to database.

Comment: You certainly need to learn the basics first. Why not to try some tutorial? At least on getting data from DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First execute your select query and get `$check1`. Then compare.

```
$qry    =  "SELECT _id_year FROM student WHERE _index='$_index'";
$exec   =  mysqli_query($con,$qry);
$result =  mysqli_fetch_object($result);
$check1 =  $result->_id_year ;
```

Also, you Don't have use **single quotes**. Try this,

```
if($_year > $check1)
{
  mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
```

Comment: This answer is toooooooo hasty

Comment: put echo for $year and $check1 and check the values of those variables

Answer (score 1):

Using [SafeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql#safemysql) the code would be almost the same as you wrote, but it will actually run these queries and also make it *safe*:

```
$check=$db->getOne("SELECT _id_year FROM student WHERE _index=?s",$_index);

if($_year > $check )
{
    $db->query("UPDATE student SET _id_year=?s WHERE _index=?s",$_year,$_index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should execute the `$check1` query first, get it's result, then compare it with you `$_year` variable

Answer (score -1):

It is always true because of the quoted field of your PHP it should not be qouted

```
 if($_year>$check1)
 {
 mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 }
```